# How to count the number of occurrences of each word in a sentence for each sentence score?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have a document of user survey:

```
Score    Comment
8        Rapid bureaucratic affairs. Reports for policy...
4        There needs to be communication or feed back f...
7        service is satisfactory
5        Good
5        There is no
10       My main reason for the product is competition ...
9        Because I have not received the results. And m...
5        no reason
```

I want to determine which keywords correspond to a higher score, and which keywords correspond to a lower score.

My idea is to construct a table of the words (or, a "word vector" dictionary), which will contain the scores it is associated with, and the number of times that score has been associated with that sentence.

Something like the following:

```
Word        Score   Count
Word1:      7       1
            4       2
Word2:      5       1
            9       1
            3       2
            2       1
Word3:      9       3
Word4:      8       1
            9       1
            4       2
...         ...     ...
```

Then, for each word, the average score is average of all the scores that word is associated with.

To do this, my code is the following:

```
word_vec = {}
# col 1 is the word, col 2 is the score, col 3 is the number of times it occurs

for i in range(len(data)):
    sentence = data['SurveyResponse'][i].split(' ')
    for word in sentence:
        word_vec['word'] = word
        if word in word_vec:
            word_vec[word] = {'Score':data['SCORE'][i], 'NumberOfTimes':(word_vec[word]['NumberOfTimes'] += 1)}
        else:
            word_vec[word] = {'Score':data['SCORE'][i], 'NumberOfTimes':1}
```

But this code gives me the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-144-14b3edc8cbd4>", line 9
    word_vec[word] = {'Score':data['SCORE'][i], 'NumberOfTimes':(word_vec[word]['NumberOfTimes'] += 1)}
                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone please show me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this piece of code

```
word_vec = {}
# col 1 is the word, col 2 is the score, col 3 is the number of times it occurs

for i in range(len(data)):
    sentence = data['SurveyResponse'][i].split(' ')
    for word in sentence:
        word_vec['word'] = word
        if word in word_vec:
            word_vec[word]['Score'] += data['SCORE'][i] # Keep accumulating the total score for each word, would be easier to find the average score later on
            word_vec[word]['NumberOfTimes'] += 1
        else:
            word_vec[word] = {'Score':data['SCORE'][i], 'NumberOfTimes':1}
```

To increment the value of 'NumberOfTimes', you can directly increment like this `word_vec[word]['NumberOfTimes'] += 1`

Comment: Thanks! Just 1 more question - how do I create and store the average scores in a new dictionary, `word_vec_avg = {}`? I tried `for k, v in word_vec.items():
    word_vec_avg[k] = v['Score']/v['NumberOfTimes']`, but it gives the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: It seems that variable v is an array from the error which you shared. can you print value of v and give the output?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the collection Counter. It permits to count the number of occurences of each word.

Here an example:

```
 from collections import Counter

 c = Counter(["jsdf","ijoiuj","je","oui","je","non","oui","je"])

 print(c)
```

Result:

```
Counter({'je': 3, 'oui': 2, 'ijoiuj': 1, 'jsdf': 1, 'non': 1})
```

You extract words from the document and put them into a list. Finally that list will be treated by the Counter to count the occurence of each word.